# To plot specific date on time series data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime

I am trying to plot specific dates on time series dataset using matplotlib. Those dates indicates some events which I would like to highlight. I want to do this for multiple dates. I was able to do it for one date which worked for me but not for multiple dates. Can someone help me out in plotting multiple dates?

```
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,10))
ax.plot(df)
ax.axvspan(date2num(datetime(2022,4,8)), date2num(datetime(2022,4,8)), 
           label="Leaks",color="red", alpha=1)
ax.legend()
ax.set_ylabel('Values')
ax.set_title('Leaks in liquid Lvl', size=28)
```

[image: The result]

Few methods I tried but they didn't work for me.

```
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
from matplotlib.dates import date3num
from matplotlib.dates import date4num


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,10))
ax.plot(df)

ax.axvspan(date2num(datetime(2022,4,8)), date2num(datetime(2022,4,8)), date3num(datetime(2022,6,22)), date3num(datetime(2022,6,22)),date4num(datetime(2022,9,2)), date4num(datetime(2022,9,2)),
           label="Leaks",color="red", alpha=1)

ax.legend()
ax.set_ylabel('Values')
ax.set_title('Leaks in liquid Lvl', size=28)

###############################################


from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
from matplotlib.dates import date3num
from matplotlib.dates import date4num


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,10))
ax.plot(df)
#ax.axvspan(date2num(datetime(2022,4,8)), date2num(datetime(2022,4,8)), 
           #label="Leaks",color="red", alpha=1)
#ax.axvspan(date3num(datetime(2022,6,22)), date3num(datetime(2022,6,22)), 
           #label="Leaks",color="red", alpha=1)
#ax.axvspan(date4num(datetime(2022,9,2)), date4num(datetime(2022,9,2)), 
           #label="Leaks",color="red", alpha=1)

ax.legend()
ax.set_ylabel('Values')
ax.set_title('Leaks in liquid Lvl', size=28)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Generate toy data
df =pd.DataFrame({'var': np.random.randint(low = 3,high=8,size=365)}, 
        index=pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', end='2022-12-31', freq='D'),

)

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
# plot the dataframe
plt.plot(df, color='g')

# list of dattes to be hilighted
line_date =['2022-04-08','2022-06-22','2022-09-02']

for mark_time in line_date:
    time_x=pd.Timestamp(mark_time) # convert to compatible format
    plt.axvline(x = time_x, color = 'b')
plt.show()
```

[image]